# How to make a simple http request in Meteor from client to server

Tags: javascript, http, meteor

I'm using Meteor for first time and i'm trying to have a simple http call within a method so i can call this method from the client.

The problem is that this async call it's keep running even if i put it within a wrapper.

Client side:

```
Meteor.call('getToken', function(error, results) {
      console.log('entered');

      if(error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log(results);
      }
    });
```

Server Side

```
Meteor.methods({
    getToken: function(){

        // App url
        var appUrl = 'myAppUrl';

        // Key credentials
        var apiKey = 'mykey';
        var apiSecret = 'mySecret';

        function asyncCall(){
            Meteor.http.call(
                'POST',
                appUrl,
                {
                    data: { 
                        key: apiKey, 
                        secret: apiSecret
                    }
                }, function (err, res) {
                    if(err){
                      return err;
                    } else {
                      return res;
                    }
                }
            );
        }

        var syncCall = Meteor.wrapAsync(asyncCall);

        // now you can return the result to client.
        return syncCall; 
    } 
});
```

I'm always getting an undefined return.
If i log the response within the http.post call i'm geting the correct response.
If i try to log the syncCall i get nothing.

I would very appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the synchronous version of [HTTP.post](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_post) in this case. Give something like this a try:

```
Meteor.methods({
  getToken: function() {
    var appUrl = 'myAppUrl';
    var data = {apiKey: 'mykey', apiSecret: 'mySecret'};
    try {
      var result = HTTP.post(appUrl, {data: data});
      return result;
    } catch (err) {
      return err;
    }
  } 
});
```

Instead of returning the `err` I'd recommend determining what kind of error was thrown and then just `throw new Meteor.Error(...)` so the client can see the error as its first callback argument.