# Extracting data out of http call

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to define a function that requires a variable to be updated while inside the HTTP call function like this:

```
getName:function(nomeID){
var link = "https://slack.com/api/users.info" ;
var arguments = {
  headers: {"User-Agent": "Meteor/1.0"},
  params: {"token": "3157110868-15807297649-cc4e782ed1",
            "user":nomeID
          }
};
var nameR=0;
HTTP.call('GET',link,arguments, Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(error,response){
  nameR=response.data.user.name;
}));
return nameR;
}
```

but the variable doesnt seem to update. Any help on how to "extract" data out of the HTTP call ( preferably without using a database)?

Comment: Is this running on the server or the client? Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33644547/server-crashing-on-http-call-with-meteor-mismatched-async-results) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093534/how-to-make-a-simple-http-request-in-meteor-from-client-to-server) question for examples.

Comment: @DavidWeldon it+s running on the server

Comment: @DavidWeldon ok i saw some of your answers and i already fixed the problem with my code, cheers ;)!